# Powershell Оповещение пользователей об истечении срока действия сертификата

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Требуется оповестить пользователя об истечении срока действия его личных сертификатов. Найти логи пользователя и его сертификат у меня получилось.

```
#Определяю логин пользователя

    $user = $env:Username 

#По логину узнаю ФИО которое хорониться в поле DisplayName

    $ADdate = GET-ADUser -Identity $user -Properies DisplayName 
    $FullName = $ADdate.DisplayName

#Переменная которая хранит в себе сколько дней осталось до истечения сертификата

    $Threshold =30

#Переменная которая хранит в себе дату до которой проверяются сертификаты

    $DeadLine = (Get-date).AddDays($Threshold)

#Поиск личных сертификатов соответствующие условию и вычисляем сколько дней осталось до истечении сертификата

    $cert = dir Cert:\CurrentUser\my | foreach {if($_.NotAfter -le $deadline -and $_.Subject -notlike $FullName) {$_.| select issuer, subject, notafter, @{label="expires in(days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).days}}}}
```

На выходе получаю:

```
Issuer CN=Issuing  CA, O=BANK, L=Moscow, DC=URAL, DC=BANK, DC=LOC, C=RU 

----------

Subject CN=Иванов Иван Иванович, OU=Users, OU=OOO BANK, DC=URAL, DC=BANK, DC=LOC

----------

NotAfter 02.08.2020 8:58:19 

----------

expires in (days)       725
```

Не понимаю как это привести к состоянию:

```
Дорогой Иванов Иван Иванович действия сертификата Issuing  CA кончается 02.08.2020 8:58:19  через 725 дней
```

Comment: что и где "привести к состоянию"?

Comment: чтоб на выходи получилось сообщение:
Дорогой Иванов Иван Иванович действия сертификата Issuing  CA кончается 02.08.2020 8:58:19  через 725 дней

Comment: в личных хоронятся много сертификатов, надо выбрать именно Иванова Ивана Ивановича и вывести ему сообщение об окончании действия его сертификата!!! и это может быть не один и не два!